# Is there a way to reset all SQL variables in a Snowflake session using Snowflake-SQL?

Tags: session-variables, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm a big fan of Session variables when I'm creating Snowflake SQL scripts, but I'm missing the functionality to reset all my variables. Is there a way to reset all Session variables with one command? (something like `UNSET ALL SESSION VARIABLES`)

The underlying problem is that I find myself making many variable declaration errors when creating Snowflake scripts. Say that I'm developing two scripts. In both scripts, I make use of a common variable "var", but I forgot to declare it in one of my scripts. I'm currently unable to detect this mistake easily in my own session.

According to the documentation [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html), Snowflake allows me to show all variables and allows me to unset multiple variables if I know their identifiers. A combination of the two is what I'm looking for.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a stored procedure for this.

I wrote one for you:

```js
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE unset_all()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({
    sqlText: "SHOW VARIABLES",    
});
stmt.execute();
var env_vars=[];
var result1 = stmt.execute();
while(result1.next()) {
  env_vars.push(result1.getColumnValue('name'));
}
if (env_vars.length > 0) {
  snowflake.createStatement({
      sqlText: "UNSET (" + env_vars + ");",    
  }).execute();
}
$$;
```

Test:

```
SET a = 'a';
SET b = 'b';
SHOW VARIABLES;
CALL unset_all();
SHOW VARIABLES;
```

Note that `EXECUTE AS CALLER` is needed for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

One a bit "ugly" way is to cancel current session:

```
SET v = 1;
SET i = 'a';

SHOW VARIABLES;
-- v ...
-- i ...

SELECT SYSTEM$ABORT_SESSION(CURRENT_SESSION()::INT);

SHOW VARIABLES;
-- empty
```

Remarks:

- when using Classic UI you will be immediately logged out, it will work with PreviewApp
- objects that depends on session will be lost(uncommitted transactions/temporary tables/session parameters and so on) - **use with caution!!!**